# How to use alias in where clause in mysql with lead lag functions

Tags: mysql, where-clause, alias

I am trying to compare value with an alias but it says scolumn not recognized. Docs says can't use alias in where clause

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        StockCode AS TopProduct,
        COUNT(CustomerID) AS mostCustomers 
    FROM
        dbfinalweek.`e-commerce`
    GROUP BY 
        StockCode 
    ORDER BY 
        mostCustomers DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT 
    StockCode AS stock, CustomerID, 
    LEAD(StockCode, 1) OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID, InvoiceDate) AS NextItem,
    LAG(StockCode, 1) OVER () AS PreviousItem,
    InvoiceDate
FROM
    dbfinalweek.`e-commerce` AS table1 
WHERE
    (table1.StockCode = (SELECT CTE.TopProduct FROM CTE)) OR 
    (table1.NextItem = (SELECT CTE.TopProduct FROM CTE))
```

Here is my query. Any idea how I could make `Table1.NextItem` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windo function can't be used directly so you must make a second cte for that`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `e-commerce` (StockCode int,CustomerID int,mostCustomers int,InvoiceDate date)
> ```

> ```
> with CTE AS
> (
>     Select 
>       StockCode as TopProduct
>         ,count(CustomerID) as mostCustomers 
>         from `e-commerce`
>       group by StockCode 
>         order by mostCustomers desc  
>         limit 1
> ),
> cte2 as(
> select 
>      StockCode as stock 
>     ,CustomerID
>     , Lead(StockCode,1) over( order by CustomerID,InvoiceDate) as NextItem
>     ,Lag(StockCode,1) over() as PreviousItem 
>     ,InvoiceDate
> from `e-commerce` )
> SELECT
> * FROM cte2
> WHERE (stock = (Select CTE.TopProduct from CTE)) OR  (NextItem=(Select CTE.TopProduct from CTE))
> ```

> ```
> stock | CustomerID | NextItem | PreviousItem | InvoiceDate
> ----: | ---------: | -------: | -----------: | :----------
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b449ae44fb7b203f81863d6ca97e7b6b)*

Comment: doesnt work... same error Unknown column table1.NextItem in having clause

Comment: table1.StockCode works fine because it is not alias. the problem is with NextItem

Comment: please add a dvfiddle to test it

Comment: so it would work without adding table1.... But now the problem is it says cannot use NextItem containing window function in this context.

Comment: i changed my answer, Window function can't be used directly, that is always a pain

Comment: You saved my life sir...Thank you so much

Comment: Why windows function dont work in where clause: https://learnsql.com/blog/window-functions-not-allowed-in-where/#:~:text=This%20order%20of%20operations%20implies,LAG()%20%2C%20or%20NTILE()%20.

Comment: explains why you made two separate windows(CTEs) and then the third window(next select) as well...